# I am trying to use gcs bucket as the volume in gke pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, docker-volume, google-kubernetes-engine

I am getting the error:

> error validating "mysql.yaml": error validating data:
>   ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes[0]): unknown
>   field "path" in io.k8s.kubernetes.pkg.api.v1.Volume; )

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:5.6
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql
                  key: password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mapping-sandbox-test
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mapping-sandbox-test
          path: gs://<bucket-name>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Deployment object looks correct using name and path as keys. You can see an example on [how to mount a GCS bucket on kubernetes here](https://github.com/maciekrb/gcs-fuse-sample)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gcsfuse-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gcsfuse-test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gcsfuse-test
          image: gcr.io/some-repo/gcs-fuse:latest
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
            capabilities:
              add:
                - SYS_ADMIN
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["gcsfuse", "-o", "nonempty", "some-bucket", "/mnt/some-bucket"]
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["fusermount", "-u", "/mnt/some-bucket"]
```

[This Stack Overflow question might help too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966832/mount-google-storage-bucket-in-google-container).

Comment: I tried this but I did am getting CrashLoopBackOff  error. I used the same Dockerfile and  I replaced bucket with my bucket. My container has complete access to the bucket as well. please check this file once.

Comment: what's the output for `kubectl describe pod <podname>` ?